# ¿Cómo puedo obtener las propiedades de un objeto?

Tags: javascript

En JavaScript, puedo obtener sin ningún problemas los valores de las propiedades del objeto pero y si, ¿Quiero obtener el nombre de las propiedades? ¿Cómo lo hago?

```js
var persona = {
  nombre: "Jose",
  apellido: "Vaca",
  edad: 21,
  colorOjos: "Marron"
}

for (var i in persona) {
  document.writeln('<p>' + persona[i] + '</p>');
}
```

¿Cómo puedo decirle a JavaScript que me regrese `nombre`, `apellido`, `edad` y `colorOjos`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con `Object.keys()` obtienes los **keys** en un arreglo (array):

```js
var persona = {
  nombre: "Jose",
  apellido: "Vaca",
  edad: 21,
  colorOjos: "Marron"
}
document.writeln(Object.keys(persona));

for (var i in persona) {
  document.writeln('<p>' + persona[i] + '</p>');
}
```

Documentación:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys

Answer (score 1):

Podría usar un `For` simple

```js
var persona = {
     nombre: "Jose",
     apellido: "Vaca",
     edad: 21,
     colorOjos: "Marron"
     }

    for (key in persona){
      alert( key );
    }
```

o con la ayuda de  Jquery podría hacerlo con un [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```js
 var persona = {
         nombre: "Jose",
         apellido: "Vaca",
         edad: 21,
         colorOjos: "Marron"
         }

    $.each( persona , function( key, value ) {
      alert( key );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aquí el "punto clave" es el uso de "key", pero no se menciona en la descripción.